# Sliding between activity with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

As I read the documentation, sliding between views happens between fragment. I am developing an app as Activity<->Fragment relationship, that is I can have multiple fragments on single activity. I find this sensible and more easier to comprehend. My problem arises when I would like to convert my existing Activity with 2 fragments to slide between another activity that is possible to have multiple fragment. I am considering Fragments within Fragments but I am not comfortable with this approach. I would like to know if there is a way to do this on Android?

Second thing is, all the tutorials point to a fragment which contains a place holder for data to view. It is easy to implement in this way. But I am not paging through some sort of data source, I am paging through activities. I need somehow a reliable communication between two activities such that ActivityB send data to ActivityA. Though I am not implementing many activities to leaf through but only 2 activities. I am currently implementing the code as describe on the docs but it seems this is not what I want. I saw some application that does similar thing and I wanted similar feature as well. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what your problem is. But you can send data when you switch from one activity to the other, with intent.
Example from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html: 

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

Comment: That's right we can do that, but this is about swiping between views. I want something like on 1st page it shows a video player which contains two fragment: Fragment1>TitleBar and Fragment2>Video on 2nd Page I can show some kind of list of available videos. The problem is I already have a code and its quite hefty now. I have fragments communicating to other fragment by their underlying activities.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution now. What I did is I created a Fragment which will add 2 child fragments. Those 2 child fragments has List and a Filter fragments. Instead of doing it through Activity, I did it through Fragments. In case someone encounters similar problem:

So here is what the Parent Fragment Looked like:

```
package com.neonwarge.android.note;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class PagerActivity extends BackboneActivity implements     NoteListSubFragment.NoteListCallback
{
private final static int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private int mCurrentPage;

private HomePageFragment mHomePageFragment;
private NoteDateSelectorFragment mNoteDateSelectorFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "PagerActivity.onCreate() has been called.");
    setTargetLayout(R.layout.activity_pager);

    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_home_screen_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mCurrentPage = 0;
    mPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage);
}

private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                mHomePageFragment = new HomePageFragment();
                return mHomePageFragment;

            case 1:
                mNoteDateSelectorFragment = new NoteDateSelectorFragment();
                return mNoteDateSelectorFragment;

            default: break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}


@Override
public void onNoteItemSelected(Note note , int type)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , NoteActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NoteFragment.EXTRA_NOTE_ID, note.getNoteID());
    intent.putExtra(NoteFragment.EXTRA_INSTANCE_TYPE, type);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent , 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(request, result, intent);

    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "PageActivity.onActivityResult() called.");

    if(intent == null)
        return;

    switch(mCurrentPage)
    {
        case 0:
            mHomePageFragment.updateSubFragments(request, result, intent);
            break;

        case 1:
            break;

        default:
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "PagerActivity.onActivityResult(): page not supported.");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Noticed here that the two Fragment I suppose to have (which originally being added by the activity) are now enclosed to a Parent Fragment named HomePageFragment.

Here is how I add two Child-Fragments in the HomePageFragment:

```
public class HomePageFragment extends Fragment
{
private NoteListSubFragment mNoteListSubFragment;
private NoteFilterSubFragment mNoteFilterSubFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setRetainInstance(true);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homescreen, container, false);

    // add sub_fragments here.
    FragmentManager cfm = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction cft = cfm.beginTransaction();

    mNoteListSubFragment = new NoteListSubFragment();
    mNoteFilterSubFragment = new NoteFilterSubFragment();

    cft.add(R.id.layout_fragment_container_filter, mNoteFilterSubFragment);
    cft.add(R.id.layout_fragment_container_list, mNoteListSubFragment);
    cft.commit();

    return v;
}

public void updateSubFragments(int request, int result, Intent intent)
{
     if(mNoteListSubFragment != null)
         mNoteListSubFragment.onNoteListUpdated();  
}

}
```

As you can see on these two lines:

```
        cft.add(R.id.layout_fragment_container_filter, mNoteFilterSubFragment);
    cft.add(R.id.layout_fragment_container_list, mNoteListSubFragment);
```

This actually targets the FrameLayout to which this fragment will appear. Originally the I just simply reused the Activity's layout file and inflate the fragment onto their respective places:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="7dp">

<FrameLayout         
    android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_container_filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout         
    android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_container_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this would help someone.